# Curl post requests with Spotify client id & secret return invalid client

Tags: ruby, authentication, curl, encoding, base64

I'm following Spotify's [client credentials authorization flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow), but all of my curl requests are returning `{"error":"invalid_client"}` each time. Here are the instructions from Spotify:

> The request will include parameters in the request body:
>
> - grant_type - Set to “client_credentials”.
>
> The header of this POST request must contain the following parameter:
>
> - Authorization - A Base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key. The field must have the format: `Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>`

They also include an example of a curl request:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4ZjAw...WY0MzE=" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

Following their example, so far I've tried curl requests with:

- client_id and client_secret plain
- both base64 encoded seperately
- only one or the other encoded
- both encoded as one string with the colon
- both encoded as one string without the colon
- each of the above with a regenerated client secret

I'm using Ruby's `Base64#encode64` method to encode. Still no luck. Any helpful hints?

Comment: Does the curl request work for you? Can you post the exact Ruby code you're trying to use?

Comment: The curl request was not working; I was trying to get that to work before trying it in the actual Rails app. But I figured it out - you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got it working - passing my client_id and client_secret, separated by a colon, to `Base64.strict_encode64` (NOT `Base64.encode64`) and then passing that to the above curl request gets a 200 response with an access token. Apparently `encode64` was not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when I ran the curl command in my terminal.

```
-bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

Solved by using single quotes instead of double quotes.